# Probability measure of trapezoidal area

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Let $Pr_{(X,Y)}$ be a probability distribution of a random vector $(X,Y)$. Let $F$ be the cumulative distribution function of $(X,Y)$. Define
$$
\mathcal{A}\equiv \{(x,y): x\leq 2 \text{ and }x-y\leq 3\}
$$
Is there a way to express $Pr_{(X,Y)}(\mathcal{A})$ as
$$
(*)\quad  \sum_{k=1}^K F(a_k, b_k)\times c_k
$$
for some finite $K$ and $\{a_k, b_k, c_k\}_{k=1}^K$?

---

Note: if $(X,Y)$ had a uniform distribution, then we could write
$$
Pr_{(X,Y)}(\mathcal{A})=Pr_{(X,Y)}((-\infty,2]\times [-1,\infty))+\frac{1}{2}Pr_{(X,Y)}((-\infty,2]\times (-\infty,-1])
$$
which can be rewritten as $(*)$.
However, I wonder whether we could do something similar for the general case without uniformity.

Comment: There is no such thing as "a probability measure of a random vector". There is the notion, though, of **the** probability **distribution** of a random vector (which is a measure).

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: In your formula $$
Pr_{(X,Y)}(\mathcal{A})=F((-\infty,2]\times [-1,\infty))+\frac{1}{2}F((-\infty,2]\times (-\infty,-1]),
$$ you treat $F$ as a function of a set, whereas in fact $F$ is a function of pair of real numbers.

Comment: Yes, I have edited that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this cannot be done in general. Indeed, let $A:=\mathcal A$. You want to express
$$P((X,Y)\in A)=Ef(X,Y)$$
as
$$\sum_{k=1}^K c_k F(a_k,b_k)=Eg(X,Y),$$
where
$$f(x,y):=1(x\le2,x-y\le3)$$
and
$$g(x,y):=\sum_{k=1}^K c_k 1(x\le a_k,y\le b_k).$$
However, for any choice of the numbers $a_k,b_k,c_k$, there will be some $(x_*,y_*)\in\mathbb R^2$ such that  $f(x_*,y_*)\ne g(x_*,y_*)$. Letting the random pair $(X,Y)$ take value $(x_*,y_*)$ with probability $1$, we get
$$P((X,Y)\in A)=Ef(X,Y)=f(x_*,y_*)\ne g(x_*,y_*)=Eg(X,Y)=\sum_{k=1}^K c_k F(a_k,b_k),$$
so that $P(A)\ne\sum_{k=1}^K c_k F(a_k,b_k)$.

Comment: Thanks. What is $E$ in your notation (in front of $f$ and $g$)?

Comment: @TEX : As usual, $E$ denotes the expectation.